# Saxon Xalan JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, saxon, xalan

I have a JSP which attaches a XSL to an XML document pulled from a database. The application is using the Saxon Parser but my XML needs to use the Xalan one. Can a JSP page override which parser to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using TransformerFactory which was using the default (Saxon) I am using the class TransformerFactoryImpl which is specfic to Xalan. All seems to be working.